# Load a php template and put a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, php-5.3

I have a template call game.php :

```
<div id="bonus-pub" class="not-display">
    <section id="" class="generique">
        <div id="">
            content
            <div id="rtr"></div>
            <div id="gfgf class="not-display">
                <h2>gfgf</h2>
                <p>dsfdsfds</p>
                <p class="GC_fdfdfd">
                    <a class="dfdf">Close</a>            </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Now I have another view whitch is open as a popup after an action generique.php:

```
<section> 
<?php require($file_view);?>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.modal').addClass('generic');
    }())
</script>
```

And a have another file charge with js actions. In this file I need to create a .js call to load the `<div id="bonus-pub" class="not-display">` into template generique.php, I tried :

```
<script>
document.getElementById('bonus-pub').setAttribute('class','display-block');
</script>
```

But this fonction only put the div into page not in popup windows. So the probleme is that I want to put `<div id="bonus-pub" class="not-display">` from template `game.php` into `generique.php` after an action. Help me please!! Thx in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Fixed the native JS and jQuery mix.

Have you tried this instead of using setAttribute:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('bonus-pub').style.display = "block";
</script>
```

Comment: I get the error in console : TypeError: document.getElementById(...).css is not a function

Comment: @Gigel My apologies, I mixed JS and jQuery - try my revision

Comment: The div>bonus-pub is diplayed out of my generique.php :(

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement can be full filled using ajax. In game.php store all the div data in a php variable and echo that variable to the ajax call.

```
game.php

<?php
$ret = '<div id="bonus-pub" class="not-display">
    <section id="" class="generique">
        <div id="">
            content
            <div id="rtr"></div>
            <div id="gfgf class="not-display">
                <h2>gfgf</h2>
                <p>dsfdsfds</p>
                <p class="GC_fdfdfd">
                    <a class="dfdf">Close</a>            </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>';


echo $ret;
?>
```

after your mentioned action make an ajax call for the game.php page

```
$.ajax({
url:'game.php',
method:'post',
success: function(response)
{
    //you have your div data in this response
}

fail: function(response)
{
 //your ajax request  failed
}
});
```

Comment: The ajax call is in generique.php?

Comment: But in game.php I have multiple divs but I want to pass only the div>bonus-pub

Comment: then i think it is better to store this part of code in another file